# Makefile does not take effect

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation

i want to compile coreutils-5.0 with gcc-9.4.And an error occurred that "undefined reference to `floor' "

I add -lm to makefile like this CFLAGS = -g -O2 -lm ,then i compile the code .But it's still wrong.

Comment: Please improve your question: [MCVE]

Comment: `-lm` specifies a link library.  It indeed is not appropriate for `CFLAGS`.  It's very suspicious that such an error arises in a widely used, well-maintained package, so I would be inclined to guess that you're not following its build instructions properly.

Comment: I used default configure and compilation failed.Then i add CFLAGS='-lm' when runing ./configure,it compiled successfully but it will cover the previous configure like " CFLAGS='-g -O2' ".Then i add LDFLAGS='-lm' when runing ./configure,it's still wrong when runing make.It seems that the Makefile change does not take effect